# .NET TPL lambdas and closures - will this code work

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, closures, task-parallel-library

So I'm trying to use the TPL features in .NET 4.0 and have some code like this (don't laugh):

```
/// <summary>Fetches a thread along with its posts.  Increments the thread viewed counter.</summary>
public Thread ViewThread(int threadId)
{
   // Get the thread along with the posts
   Thread thread = this.Context.Threads.Include(t => t.Posts)
       .FirstOrDefault(t => t.ThreadID == threadId);

   // Increment viewed counter
   thread.NumViews++;
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
       try {
           this.Context.SaveChanges();
       }
       catch (Exception ex) {
           this.Logger.Error("Error viewing thread " + thread.Title, ex);
       }

       this.Logger.DebugFormat(@"Thread ""{0}"" viewed and incremented.", thread.Title);
   });

   return thread;
}
```

So my immediate concerns with the lambda are this.Context (my entity framework datacontext member), this.Logger (logger member) and thread (used in the logger call).  Normally in the QueueUserWorkItem() days, I would think these would need to be passed into the delegate as part of a state object.  Are closures going to be bail me out of needing to do that?

Another issue is that the type that this routine is in implements IDisposable and thus is in a using statement.  So if I do something like...

```
using (var bl = new ThreadBL()) {
            t = bl.ViewThread(threadId);
        }
```

... am I going to create a race between a dispose() call and the TPL getting around to invoking my lambda?

Currently I'm seeing the context save the data back to my database but no logging - no exceptions either.  This could be a configuration thing on my part but something about this code feels odd.  I don't want to have unhandled exceptions in other threads.  Any input is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your question on closures, yes this is exactly what closures are about. You don't worry about passing state, instead it is captured for you from any outer context and copied onto a compiler supplied class which is also where the closure method will be defined. The compiler does a lot of magic here to make you're life simple. If you want to understand more I highly recommend picking up Jon Skeet's C# in Depth. The chapter on closures is actually [available here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx).

As for your specific implementation, it will not work mainly for the exact problem you mentioned: the Task will be scheduled at the end of `ViewThread`, but potentially not execute before your `ThreadBL` instance is disposed of.

Comment: I've moved past this implementation but for future reference - if I didn't dispose of the ThreadBL instance would I be guaranteed that the GC won't finalize the instance?  I guess what I'm asking is: do closures count as something having a reference to your object as far as the runtime and garbage collection is concerned?  Sounds like it but I'm not sure I understand 100%  Thanks for the link to Skeet's article.

Comment: Yes, because it's the "this" that you're referring to in your closure it would be "captured" by the closure and a reference would be held around in that case. The question is how would you the dispose of ThreadBL in that case? It would go against the normal unit-of-work pattern. You're usually better off not nesting thread/task logic inside BL type classes and letting the way the app uses them decide when/how to thread the work.

Comment: Re: disposing of the object: how then would you suggest to have the act of viewing a thread also increment the viewed counter (without waiting on the bump)?  It seemed to me an ideal case for a "business logic" method... I didn't want to bother the client that it should have to remember to increment a counter every time it displayed a thread.  Btw, you've more than answered the original question, thanks.

Comment: The way it's designed right now, you can't really do it cleanly. Your ThreadBL seems to be somewhat designed for the unit-of-work pattern, but you're commiting work inside its methods which breaks the pattern. What you would have to do is stop calling SaveChanges in your ThreadBL methods and actually expose a SaveChanges on ThreadBL itself so that the owner (the app) can dictate how/when changes are saved. Once you've done that the app can make all its call to ViewThread synchronously and then it can queue saving the changes out to a Task and dispose of the ThreadBL when that task completes.